# How do I send drop down list selection to my controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, submit, html.dropdownlistfor

I will start by saying that I am very new to asp.net MVC, but have a project that i need to complete. That being said, any help is greatly appreciated.

I have two cascading dropdown lists created and populating with MVC, LINQ to SQL and Ajax that i need the selections brought into my controller. I am trying to simply create and send an email with my form data in the body and have been stuck for some time. The Javascript returns the Id number from the database, but i need the "StateName and "CountyName" that is associated with the Id rather than just the Id. For a reference, this is the method that I used to create what I have now, but there was no explanation on how to submit the selections.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730953/Cascading-Dropdown-List-With-MVC-LINQ-to-SQL-and-A

Here is my Controller

```
public class AddressController : Controller
{
    private IAddressRepository _repository;

    public AddressController() : this(new AddressRepository())
    {
    }

    public AddressController(IAddressRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AddressModel model = new AddressModel();
        model.AvailableUSStates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please select-", Value = "Selects items" });
        var usstates = _repository.GetAllUSStates();
        foreach (var usstate in usstates)
        {
            model.AvailableUSStates.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = usstate.USStateName,
                    Value = usstate.USStateID.ToString()
                });
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetCountiesByUSStateID(string USStateID)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(USStateID))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("USStateID");
        }
        int id = 0;
        bool isValid = Int32.TryParse(USStateID, out id);
        var counties = _repository.GetAllCountiesByUSStateID(id);
        var result = (from s in counties
                      select new
                      {
                          id = s.CountyID,
                          name = s.CountyName
                      }).ToList();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ContentResult SimplePost(string submittedState)
    {
        string result = string.Format(submittedState);
        return new ContentResult { Content = result };
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index([Bind(Include = "USStateName, CountyName")] AddressModel addressModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("address@gmail.com");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("address@hotmail.com"));
            message.Subject = "";

            message.Body = "";

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(message);
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
namespace msifla.Models
{
public class AddressModel
{
    public AddressModel()
    {
        AvailableUSStates = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AvailableCounties = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
    [Display(Name = "USState")]
    public int USStateID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableUSStates { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "County")]
    public int CountyID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableCounties { get; set; }
}
}
```

View

```
@model msifla.Models.AddressModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $("#USStateID").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var ddlCounties = $("#CountyID");
            var countiesProgress = $("#counties-loading-progress");
            $('.selItem').remove();
            var selectedItem2 = $('<p class="selItem">' + selectedItem + '</p>');
            $('.usState').append(selectedItem2);
            //$('.usState').append($('<p>This works here</p>'));
         countiesProgress.show();
         $.ajax({
             cache: false,
             type: "GET",
             url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetCountiesByUSStateID"))",
                data: { "USStateID": selectedItem },
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlCounties.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        ddlCounties.append($('<option> </option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));

                    });
                    alert(option.name);
                    countiesProgress.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
                    countiesProgress.hide();
                }

         });

    });

    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USStateID)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.USStateID, Model.AvailableUSStates)
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountyID)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountyID, Model.AvailableCounties)
    <span id="counties-loading-progress" style="display: none;">Please wait..</span>

  </div>
  <div class="usState"></div>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Save"/>
  <label id="stateLabel"></label>
}
```

Let me know if you need to see the repository.
Thank you in advance for your help.

**Edit**
I know this is old, but I found a solution and wanted to post it here. It has been a while since i fixed my issue so I don't remember where I found the solution, but here it is:

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AddressModel model = new AddressModel();
        model.AvailableUSStates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please select-", Value = "Selects items" });
        model.AvailableLibraries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please select-", Value = "Selects items" });


        var usstates = _repository.GetAllUSStates();
        foreach (var usstate in usstates)
        {
            model.AvailableUSStates.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = usstate.USStateName,
                Value = usstate.USStateID.ToString()
            });
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetLibrariesByUSStateID(string USStateID)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(USStateID))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("USStateID");
        }
        int id = 0;
        bool isValid = Int32.TryParse(USStateID, out id);
        var counties = _repository.GetAllLibrariesByUSStateID(id);
        var result = (from s in counties
                      select new
                      {
                          id = s.LibraryID,
                          name = s.LibraryName
                      }).ToList();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(AddressModel model)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfirmModel model2 = new ConfirmModel();

            model2.USStateName = SelectedUSState(model.USStateID.ToString());

            model2.CountyName = SelectedCounty(model.LibraryID.ToString(), model.USStateID.ToString());
            model2.CountyID = model.LibraryID;
            model2.clientID = model.clientId.ToString();

            return View("Confirmation", model2);


        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Confirmation(AddressModel model2)
    {
        ConfirmModel model = new ConfirmModel();

        model.USStateName = SelectedUSState(model2.USStateID.ToString());
        model.CountyName = SelectedCounty(model2.LibraryID.ToString(), model2.USStateID.ToString());

        var USStateName = model.USStateName;

        return View(model);
    }

    //[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    //public ActionResult Confirmation(ConfirmModel model)
    //{
    //    string USStateName = model.USStateName;

    //    return View();
    //}

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult submitConfirmation(ConfirmModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string usStateName = model.USStateName;
            string countyName = model.CountyName;

            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string ipAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
            string ipAddress2 = Request.ServerVariables["Remote_Addr"];
            string userAgent = Request.UserAgent;


            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("someone@domain.com");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("someoneElse@domain.com"));
            message.Subject = "Subject";

            // You need to use Index because that is the name declared above
            message.Body = "<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>" +
                "<pre>State:\t\t" + usStateName + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>County:\t\t" + countyName + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>Remote Name:\t" + ipAddress + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>Remote User:\t" + userAgent + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>Date:\t" + dateTime.ToLongDateString() + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>Time:\t" + dateTime.ToLongTimeString() + "</pre>" +
                "\n" 
                "</body>";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(message);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult resetConfirmation()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


    public string SelectedUSState(string USStateID)
    {
        ViewBag.YouSelected = USStateID.ToString();
        AddressModel model = new AddressModel();
        int id = 0;
        int usStateIDInt = int.Parse(USStateID);
        bool isValid = Int32.TryParse(USStateID, out id);
        var usstates = _repository.GetAllUSStates();
        var state = from s in _repository.GetAllUSStates()
                    where s.USStateID.ToString() == USStateID
                    select s.USStateName;
        var currUSState = state.SingleOrDefault();
        //var currUSStatename = usstates.te

        //model.USStateName = currUSState;
        ViewBag.currUSState = currUSState;
        return currUSState;
    }

    public string SelectedCounty(string CountyID, string USStateID)
    {
        AddressModel model = new AddressModel();
        int id = 0;
        int countyIDInt = int.Parse(CountyID);
        bool isValid = Int32.TryParse(CountyID, out id);
        int usStateIDInt = int.Parse(USStateID);
        var counties = _repository.GetAllLibrariesByUSStateID(usStateIDInt);
        var county = from s in counties
                     where s.LibraryID.ToString() == CountyID
                     select s.LibraryName;
        var currCounty = county.SingleOrDefault();

        ViewBag.currCounty = currCounty;
        return currCounty;

    }
```

Model

```
public class AddressModel
{
    public AddressModel()
    {
        AvailableUSStates = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AvailableLibraries = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }


    [Display(Name = "USState")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Please choose a State"))]
    public int USStateID { get; set; }
    //public string USStateName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableUSStates { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Library")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Please chose a Library for the selected State"))]
    public int LibraryID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableLibraries { get; set; }
}

public class ConfirmModel
{

    [Display(Name = "State Name")]
    public string USStateName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "County Name")]
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model msifla2.Models.MSIProModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HCOrder";
}

<script type="text/javascript"          src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>*@
@*<script src="~/Scripts/cascade.js"></script>*@

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#USStateDDL").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var ddlLibraries = $("#LibraryID");
            var librariesProgress = $("#libraries-loading-progress");
            librariesProgress.show();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetLibrariesByUSStateID"))",
                data: { "USStateID": selectedItem },
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlLibraries.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        ddlLibraries.append($('<option>Select a Library</option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
                    });
                    librariesProgress.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve libraries.');
                    librariesProgress.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@*<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#USStateDDL').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    data: { selectedValue: $('#USStateDDL').val() },
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert('#USStateDDL').val();
                    }
                })
                var selected = $(this).val();
                alert(selected + " 1 selected")
                $('#USStateLabel').load(input)
            });
        });
    </script>*@





<div class="jumbotron">
    </div>
    <div class="container article">
        <div data-ng-app="myModule" class="col-md-9 article_main container-fluid">
            <h2>Header</h2>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Address", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="edit-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USStateID, new { id = "USStateLabel", @class = "col-xs-3" })
                </div>
                <div class="edit-field, col-xs-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.USStateID, Model.AvailableUSStates, new { @class = "form-control dropdowns", id = "USStateDDL" })
                </div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LibraryID, new { @class = "col-xs-3" })
                <div class=" col-xs-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LibraryID, Model.AvailableLibraries, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3" style="padding-top:5px;">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" class="btn-success btn" />
                </div>

            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Confirm View

```
@model msifla2.Models.ConfirmModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Confirmation";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Confirmation</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("submitConfirmation", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div data-ng-app="myModule" class="col-md-9 article_main">
    <div>
        <h4>Please check your order and select <b>Confirm</b> to submit</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USStateName, new { @class = "col-xs-3" })
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.USStateName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.USStateName)
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountyName, new { @class = "col-xs-3" })
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.CountyName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountyName)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" formaction="/home/submitConfirmation" value="Confirm" />
    <input type="submit" formaction="/Home/resetConfirmation" value="Reset" />
</div>
}
```

I think I included everything. Let me know if you see something missing, but it's working for me.

Comment: beurk, so much javascript code.
Why not use partial views?

Comment: I will look into using partial views, however, I don't see where that helps with actually using the selected value from the drop down box that i have. Please correct me if I'm wrong, and provide an example.

Comment: if you have the ID, you can have a call like $.ajax({url:'getPartialDDl?Id=...',success:function (data) { ddlCounties.load(data)}
Then you have to make your method getPartialDDl return the correct partial view which contains the dropdownlist.
But yes it does not help to get the selected value (i read "The Javascript returns the Id number from the database" so i thought this part was ok.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but I found a solution and wanted to post it here. It has been a while since i fixed my issue so I don't remember where I found the solution, but here it is:

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AddressModel model = new AddressModel();
        model.AvailableUSStates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please select-", Value = "Selects items" });
        model.AvailableLibraries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please select-", Value = "Selects items" });


        var usstates = _repository.GetAllUSStates();
        foreach (var usstate in usstates)
        {
            model.AvailableUSStates.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = usstate.USStateName,
                Value = usstate.USStateID.ToString()
            });
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetLibrariesByUSStateID(string USStateID)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(USStateID))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("USStateID");
        }
        int id = 0;
        bool isValid = Int32.TryParse(USStateID, out id);
        var counties = _repository.GetAllLibrariesByUSStateID(id);
        var result = (from s in counties
                      select new
                      {
                          id = s.LibraryID,
                          name = s.LibraryName
                      }).ToList();
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(AddressModel model)
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfirmModel model2 = new ConfirmModel();

            model2.USStateName = SelectedUSState(model.USStateID.ToString());

            model2.CountyName = SelectedCounty(model.LibraryID.ToString(), model.USStateID.ToString());
            model2.CountyID = model.LibraryID;
            model2.clientID = model.clientId.ToString();

            return View("Confirmation", model2);


        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Confirmation(AddressModel model2)
    {
        ConfirmModel model = new ConfirmModel();

        model.USStateName = SelectedUSState(model2.USStateID.ToString());
        model.CountyName = SelectedCounty(model2.LibraryID.ToString(), model2.USStateID.ToString());

        var USStateName = model.USStateName;

        return View(model);
    }

    //[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    //public ActionResult Confirmation(ConfirmModel model)
    //{
    //    string USStateName = model.USStateName;

    //    return View();
    //}

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult submitConfirmation(ConfirmModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string usStateName = model.USStateName;
            string countyName = model.CountyName;

            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            string ipAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;
            string ipAddress2 = Request.ServerVariables["Remote_Addr"];
            string userAgent = Request.UserAgent;


            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress("someone@domain.com");
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("someoneElse@domain.com"));
            message.Subject = "Subject";

            // You need to use Index because that is the name declared above
            message.Body = "<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>" +
                "<pre>State:\t\t" + usStateName + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>County:\t\t" + countyName + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>Remote Name:\t" + ipAddress + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>Remote User:\t" + userAgent + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>Date:\t" + dateTime.ToLongDateString() + "</pre>" +
                "<pre>Time:\t" + dateTime.ToLongTimeString() + "</pre>" +
                "\n" 
                "</body>";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Send(message);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult resetConfirmation()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


    public string SelectedUSState(string USStateID)
    {
        ViewBag.YouSelected = USStateID.ToString();
        AddressModel model = new AddressModel();
        int id = 0;
        int usStateIDInt = int.Parse(USStateID);
        bool isValid = Int32.TryParse(USStateID, out id);
        var usstates = _repository.GetAllUSStates();
        var state = from s in _repository.GetAllUSStates()
                    where s.USStateID.ToString() == USStateID
                    select s.USStateName;
        var currUSState = state.SingleOrDefault();
        //var currUSStatename = usstates.te

        //model.USStateName = currUSState;
        ViewBag.currUSState = currUSState;
        return currUSState;
    }

    public string SelectedCounty(string CountyID, string USStateID)
    {
        AddressModel model = new AddressModel();
        int id = 0;
        int countyIDInt = int.Parse(CountyID);
        bool isValid = Int32.TryParse(CountyID, out id);
        int usStateIDInt = int.Parse(USStateID);
        var counties = _repository.GetAllLibrariesByUSStateID(usStateIDInt);
        var county = from s in counties
                     where s.LibraryID.ToString() == CountyID
                     select s.LibraryName;
        var currCounty = county.SingleOrDefault();

        ViewBag.currCounty = currCounty;
        return currCounty;

    }
```

Model

```
public class AddressModel
{
    public AddressModel()
    {
        AvailableUSStates = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AvailableLibraries = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }


    [Display(Name = "USState")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Please choose a State"))]
    public int USStateID { get; set; }
    //public string USStateName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableUSStates { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Library")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ("Please chose a Library for the selected State"))]
    public int LibraryID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableLibraries { get; set; }
}

public class ConfirmModel
{

    [Display(Name = "State Name")]
    public string USStateName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "County Name")]
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model msifla2.Models.MSIProModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HCOrder";
}

<script type="text/javascript"          src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@*<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>*@
@*<script src="~/Scripts/cascade.js"></script>*@

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#USStateDDL").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var ddlLibraries = $("#LibraryID");
            var librariesProgress = $("#libraries-loading-progress");
            librariesProgress.show();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetLibrariesByUSStateID"))",
                data: { "USStateID": selectedItem },
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlLibraries.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        ddlLibraries.append($('<option>Select a Library</option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
                    });
                    librariesProgress.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve libraries.');
                    librariesProgress.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
@*<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#USStateDDL').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    data: { selectedValue: $('#USStateDDL').val() },
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert('#USStateDDL').val();
                    }
                })
                var selected = $(this).val();
                alert(selected + " 1 selected")
                $('#USStateLabel').load(input)
            });
        });
    </script>*@





<div class="jumbotron">
    </div>
    <div class="container article">
        <div data-ng-app="myModule" class="col-md-9 article_main container-fluid">
            <h2>Header</h2>

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Address", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="edit-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USStateID, new { id = "USStateLabel", @class = "col-xs-3" })
                </div>
                <div class="edit-field, col-xs-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.USStateID, Model.AvailableUSStates, new { @class = "form-control dropdowns", id = "USStateDDL" })
                </div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LibraryID, new { @class = "col-xs-3" })
                <div class=" col-xs-9">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LibraryID, Model.AvailableLibraries, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3" style="padding-top:5px;">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" class="btn-success btn" />
                </div>

            }

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Confirm View

```
@model msifla2.Models.ConfirmModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Confirmation";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Confirmation</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("submitConfirmation", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div data-ng-app="myModule" class="col-md-9 article_main">
    <div>
        <h4>Please check your order and select <b>Confirm</b> to submit</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USStateName, new { @class = "col-xs-3" })
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.USStateName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.USStateName)
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountyName, new { @class = "col-xs-3" })
        @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.CountyName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountyName)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" formaction="/home/submitConfirmation" value="Confirm" />
    <input type="submit" formaction="/Home/resetConfirmation" value="Reset" />
</div>
}
```

I think I included everything. Let me know if you see something missing, but it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly:

change

```
ddlCounties.append($('<option> </option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
```

to

```
ddlCounties.append($('<option> </option>').val(option.name).html(option.name));
```

your model should also have the Name.

Comment: This part of the Javascript actually builds the dependent dropdownlist for the counties. I changed the .val to .val(option.name) as you suggested and i still only get the index ID rather than the Name that the ID references.